# Writers Preference with Semaphores in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to write a **writer's preference** code to prevent a writer from being starved in the event that it's in a queue and readers skip it due to their priority. The counter checking how many readers have read is protected by a semaphore (readerCount), a try semaphore is used to indicate a reader is trying to enter (psembufT), and the resource semaphore (psembufF).

I need to write to a text file (code written) in one Terminal window and read from the other in another window, whenever I try to read i get **Segmentation fault [core dumped]** error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
using namespace std;

#define SHM_KEY 9876                                    
#define SEMKEY  1234
struct sembuf vsembufR, psembufR, vsembufW, psembufW; 
struct sembuf vsembufF, psembufF, vsembufT, psembufT; 

int main()
{
union semun{   
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    ushort myArray[0];
} arg;

string op;
ifstream myFile;                                 // makes an ifstream object to read from myFile

int shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, 256, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int *readerCount = (int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);    
int semid = semget(SEMKEY, 2, 0777|IPC_CREAT);  // Creates two semaphores
int pause;
readerCount = 0;

psembufR.sem_num=0;                          // init reader mutex members
psembufR.sem_op=-1;
psembufR.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;
vsembufR.sem_num=0;
vsembufR.sem_op=1;
vsembufR.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

psembufF.sem_num=1;                          // resource
psembufF.sem_op=-1;
psembufF.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;
vsembufF.sem_num=1;
vsembufF.sem_op=1;
vsembufF.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

psembufW.sem_num=0;                         // writer
psembufW.sem_op=-1;
psembufW.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;
vsembufW.sem_num=0;
vsembufW.sem_op=1;
vsembufW.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

psembufT.sem_num=1;                         
psembufT.sem_op=-1;
psembufT.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;
vsembufT.sem_num=1;
vsembufT.sem_op=1;
vsembufT.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

arg.val = 1;
semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg);                
semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, arg);

 while(1){
    cout << "Reader1:\n";
    pause = getchar();                      
    semop(semid, &psembufT, 1);             
    semop(semid, &psembufR, 1);             
    cout << "count inc" << endl;    
    *readerCount++;
    if(*readerCount == 1)                   // is this first reader
        semop(semid, &psembufF, 1);         // lok resource from writers if 1st reader
    semop(semid, &vsembufR, 1);             // unlock reader mutex (for other readers)
    semop(semid, &vsembufT, 1);             // unlock try mutex (done accessing file)
    // Critical Section
    myFile.open ("myFile.txt", ios::out | ios::app); // ::app appends the myFile (new line)                                           
    if(myFile.is_open()){        
        while(getline(myFile, op)){
            cout << op << endl;             // reads
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
    semop(semid, &psembufR, 1);             // lock reader mutex (avoid race)
    *readerCount--;
    if(*readerCount == 0)                   // is this the last reader
        semop(semid, &vsembufF, 1);         // unlock resource
    semop(semid, &vsembufR, 1);             // unlock reader mutex
}
```

I think it's something to do with how I declared readerCount but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - and the picture is unnecessary. Copy the actual error output instead (but don't place it in the middle of the code).

Comment: To give context, I need all the included code, also shows whether or not I setup the semaphores correctly.

Comment: It's still not complete. Why not include the rest of the code needed to compile it? Have you looked at the core dump with a debugger? It may tell you where it segfaulted.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. I haven't tried a debugger on Ubuntu so far but I'll try now.

Comment: `ushort myArray[0];` <- forbidden zero-size array. And this can't be good: `int *readerCount = (int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);  readerCount = 0;`. You later do `*readerCount++` which would try to change the value in memory address zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readerCount = 0;` should be `*readerCount = 0;`

`readerCount` is an `int*` so when you do `readerCount = 0;` you set that pointer to point at address zero. When you later try to update the value at that address, you are most likely to get crashes.

Comment: I've tried that before and it didn't fix the problem but after doing it again it somehow fixes it. I probably forgot to compile it and ran the old executable. Thanks for all your help and sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes someone else just looking at the code magically fixes it. :-)